# 6 LEAD 3 phase motor rated at 220V on 415V supply

Tags: motor

So my PM bought a 3 phase japanese motor
(second hand) that is rated at 220V. Our system voltage is at 415V. Can i run the motor in wye configuration at 415V supply? If so, would it run without problems? (lower lifespan expected)
Driven by a VFD that runs on 380-415V.

Your help would be highly appreciated.[image]

Seems like i can't get the VFD to output 220.

[image]

Comment: Is 220V the only rating on the motor?  A picture of the motor nameplate and/or wiring diagram would nicen the question.  Divide line voltage by root 3 to get phase voltage.  You can't count on a 220V rated device at 240V, although it's close enough there is a chance it would work you'd be overloading the motor.

Comment: although we're on 415V i think i can adjust the voltage of the VFD to output 380ish so it would be close to 220V.. also wiring diagram is non-existent

Comment: Oh yes a correctly configured VFD should run it no problem so long as it's sized correctly.

Comment: so if i'd be able to get 380ish output and probably get 220v on phase voltages then i'll be fine with wye configuration? might not be able to get an output of 220v line voltage from VFD

Comment: The person who sets up your VFD will be able to tell you from the manual.  I've never installed one that couldn't voltage adjust but I assume they exist.  Motors are balanced loads and your motor has 6 leads, so you should meter continuity to make sure that's the ends of 3 separate coils, but assuming that's the type of motor, you can set it up in wye or delta to get the voltage you need.  Wye in this case.  If you set up the VFD wrongly enough in its settings you can cook the motor or the VFD even at the correct voltage though so do your research.

Comment: already tested continuity of each 3 separate coils and it's configured delta by default. Also can no longer reach the person who installed the VFD.. i'll reread the manual if i can simulate the VFD at no load so i can measure, on actual, it's output. Thanks for helping so far

Comment: Crop the photo before uploading, man. 80% of it is irrelevant.

Comment: sry. edited the pic.

Comment: How you get to "380ish so it would be close to 220V" is a mystery to me.  If you intend to use this motor I think your best approach is to get an appropriate step-down transformer so that it's being sourced by 220V.  While induction motors are quite tolerant of voltage fluxuations, you risk insulation breakdown and ultimately a short if you exceed the nameplate limits.

Comment: i'll try to simulate a run on VFD at no load. see if i can get 220.

Answer (score 1):

If the motor has six leads and three windings that have no internal connection, the nameplate ratings are almost certainly for a delta connection. For the wye connection, the voltage ratings would be 346, 346 and 380 volts. Since the nameplate indicates that the motor can operate at 346 volts for either 50 or 60 Hz and also 380 volts at 60 Hz, I would be inclined to use the wye connection and set up the VFD for 380 V, 60 Hz or 346 V at 50 Hz output for full speed. The require dmotor current would be about half of the values listed on the nameplate.

If the VFD is capable of 73 amps output with a 415 volt supply, it is designed for a motor rated about 44 kW. It would be wasted on a 22 kW motor, but if you already have it and you can set it up to provide 220 V at 60 Hz or 200 V at 60 Hz, that would be fine for the delta connection.

Comment: I'm also leaning towards setting up the VFD to output 380V (60HZ) so i can run the motor at lower current compared to running it on 220V. We also have a 4 core 6AWG cable laying around that i want to use. The VFD (also secondhand, cheapest he could find) used to drive 30kW 400V motor. Also pls explain 246V that you mentioned on wye configuration. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry. I corrected 246 to 346.

Comment: Note that you’ll need shielded cable between the VFD and the motor.